# JSF / PrimeFaces - How to display message for custom validator but not for required validation on the same component

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, jsf-2.2, mojarra

I have a JSF2 implementation using PrimeFaces.  I am using a `<p:selectOneRadio />` component.  When the user selects "No" in the radio component, I would like to show a custom message.  I have created a custom validator for this purpose, and along with the message component everything works fine.  However, the component is also required.  I do not want the "Value is required" validation error for the required component to show up in the message component.  In this case, I only want the field and the label to be highlighted.

So, the question is:  How do I specify that a given `<p:message />` component display only the error from my custom validator, and not the error from the required validator?

I saw an answer to a similar question from a few years ago that said you could set the message `for` attribute to a component that doesn't actually exist, and add the message to that component via the FacesContext.  Such as this: 
`<p:message for="fooMsg" />` ... `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("fooMsg",msg)`

However, that does not seem to work.  JSF throws an error that it cannot find the component "fooMsg".

Here is my current code.

Component:

```html
<p:outputLabel for="foo" id="foolbl"
    value="Some label text." />
<br />
<p:message for="foo" />
<p:selectOneRadio id="foo" layout="pageDirection"
    widgetVar="fooVar" required="true">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="Yes" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="No" />
<p:ajax update="@this foolbl" process="@this" />
<f:validator validatorId="FooValidator" />
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

Validator:

```java
@FacesValidator("FooValidator")
public class FooValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {

        if (value != null) {
            String sValue = (String) value;
            if (sValue.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("No")) {
                FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Summary",
                        "Detail");
                msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);

                throw new ValidatorException(msg);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this is default JSF behavior. To solve your 
problem, you could use jQuery to check if no radio button is choosen and hide the message in that 
case, for example:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:outputLabel for="foo" id="foolbl" value="Some label text." />
    <br />
    <p:message id="foomsg" for="foo" />
    <p:selectOneRadio id="foo" layout="pageDirection" widgetVar="fooVar"
        required="true">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="Yes" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="No" />
        <p:ajax process="@this" update="@this foolbl foomsg" />
        <f:validator validatorId="FooValidator" />
    </p:selectOneRadio>

    <p:commandButton process="@this foo" update="foo foolbl foomsg"
        oncomplete="if( !PF('fooVar').checkedRadio.length ) $('#form\\:foomsg').hide();" />
</h:form>
```

Have a look at the oncomplete attribute of the commandButton.